# Use Posts Page As Parent Of Single Posts - site/blog/single

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress for a site which has a blog attached and would like to display the single posts using the blog template as the parent page.

Currently **root.com** shows the front page of the site.

**root.com/blog/** shows the blog posts

but then when a single post is being viewed it's ignoring the blog section and the url looks like this **root.com/single**

Is there a way to make single.php use the blog page as it's parent?

Comment: have you tried changing your permalinks? I think setting them to `/%pagename%/%postname%/` should do the trick

Comment: I did and weirdly that outputs **root.com/single/single/**

Comment: damn that sounds nasty. ill do some testing and see what i can find

Comment: Actually %pagename% isn't a structure tag: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags

Comment: well, it was some versions ago

Comment: very frustrating, doesn't seem like there is a simple answer to this problem!

Comment: what about going cowboy style and forcing it to `/blog/%postname%/` ? it wont change if you ever change your page name, but it does do the trick

Comment: This is a commercial site, so forcing /blog/ in the permalinks isn't going to work. Thanks anyway

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira I figured this out now.

Comment: sweet. good solution

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out for those having the same issue.

Add this to your **functions.php**

```
/*
 * REWRITE THE SLUG FOR SINGLE POSTS .../BLOG/SINGLE POST
 *************************************************************/
add_action('init', 'post_slug_init');
function post_slug_init() {
  register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/blog' ),
        'query_var' => false,
        'pages'     => false,
        'supports' => array( 
            'title', 
            'editor',
            'author', 
            'thumbnail', 
            'excerpt', 
            'revisions'
        ),
));
}
```

Then you'll need to re-save your permalinks from wordpress admin and single posts will now appear with the correct permalink structure.